# How to kill a foreground service along with the application

Tags: android

I am running a foreground service which is doing some work in the background while the user is interacting  with my application.The problem which occurs is that when the user comes out of the application and kills the application from the home screen the service is not destroyed.Is there any way to kill the service when my application dies.

Comment: Having the same problem....

Answer (score 6):

With "kills the application from the home screen" I'm assuming you mean swiping away the app from the task manager? In that case, there is a [convenient callback in the Service class that lets you handle this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)).

Simply override that method and call `stopSelf()`.

Comment: Yes by "kills the application from home screen" I mean that the user swiping away the app from the recent app list and thus is removing the app from memory.

Comment: I just tried this and its working.Thanks a lot.I was stuck on this since yesterday and couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I wanted this!!

Answer (score 3):

You can do following to stop the service
call `stopService` method in `onDestroy` method of activity
hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I think that the problem is killing with APPLICATION, not with ACTIVITY.

Answer (score 0):

Just call [stopService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29)() for your service in [onDestroy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)() method of your main Activity.

Comment: `onTerminate()` in an `Application` is never called. Check the documentation and you'll see: "This method is for use in emulated process environments."

Comment: CallingstopService() in  onDestroy() method in main activity also works.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why do you make the service foreground? 
If it's only doing work while the user interacts with your application, 
maybe you should not keep it foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling `stopService(intent);` in my MainActivity where I call the service from another Class.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
     
        stopService(intent);
    }
```

But as For the yourservice.class needed to have the `onDestroy` method, it is crucial.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {

        super.onDestroy();
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
        
    }
```

Comment: Be warned that this will stop the service if the screen is rotated or if the colour theme is changed, as activities are recreated for these configuration changes